# How to check every Nth entry in a mysql database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find the first entry in our huge database where "foo" first started appearing, but this query is too slow:

```
select min(id)
from mytable
where data like '%foo%';
```

I'd be happy to count by millions to get close enough, but this query doesn't seem to run any faster:

```
select min(id)
from mytable
where mod(id, 1000000) = 0
and data like '%foo%';
```

Any idea how to get mysql to only check every millionth entry?  The only thing I can think of is to have a temporary table with the first integers and joining on that, multiplying each integer by 1000000.

Comment: _“Any idea how to get mysql to only check every millionth entry?”_ – this question implies that you are doing things wrong even before this point. You should (under normal circumstances) never be in need of such an approach where you tell the database _where_ (or how) it should search yourself. Most likely this problem can be fixed by using proper indexes. (Although a wildcard search with `like '%foo%'` is of course problematic in its very nature, and an index on that column will most likely not fix this. But neither will attempts to meddle with how search is done yourself.)

Comment: The data is too big to index, especially for my one query.

Comment: would it be possible to calculate the id of every nth row and retrieve that row specifically and then test the data in it? It will be very quick as it will do an index lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Your second query is most likely running *slower* because of the added `mod(id, 1000000) = 0` that MySQL must check for each `id` that it finds.

To get this to move faster, you ought to have an index on `data` column.

Also, use of `LIMIT` would probably help you like so:

```
select min(id)
from mytable
where data like '%foo%'
order by id
limit 0,1000000
```

That will search only the first 0 - 100000 rows. If you don't find what you want, then increment the limit -- `1000000, 2000000` to only look at 1000000 - 2000000 rows.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to check every millionth row, not a million at a time.

Comment: then change limit accordingly. In your case, change it to `999999,1000000` and offset accordingly. `limit` is your friend. I think that's a much better solution than `where mod(id, 1000000) = 0` as `where mod(id, 1000000) = 0` forces a computation on *every* `id`

Comment: on second thought, no. You don't want to only check every millionth row, do you? That's assuming that on some millionth row you'll find your data. You have no reason to assume that.

Comment: We started adding "foo" to every entry.  I'll edit my question to make that explicit.

Comment: do you have an estimate of *when* you started adding that? Then you could skip some number of entries that you're certain won't contain "foo". I'm pretty sure what you're looking for is my answer -- I don't think there's much else to be done in your situation. Best of luck

Comment: Also there's a contradiction in saying that you want to know the *first* occurrence of something, yet you intend to only check every *millionth* row, skipping 999999 each time you check